# C++ - Fixing text from an input file

Tags: c++, file, text

So the assignment is to fix a text.

Example input :

jaMEs  ,  mY  neIgHBor  , Is  A  dOcTor . he SPoke eaSIlY  ,  CLEarly And eloQuENtly.

Expected output:

James, my neighbor, is a doctor. He spoke easily, clearly and eloquently.

I've managed to fix all the "problems" but I can't seem to get it to capitalize the first letter of the second sentence.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    ifstream fin("vhod.txt");
    ofstream fout("izhod.txt");
    string s;
     int i=0;

    if (fin.is_open() && fout.is_open()){

            while (getline(fin, s)) {

            for(int i=0; s[i]; i++){

            if (s[i] == ' '&& (s[i+1]== ',' || s[i+1]== '.' || s[i+1]== '!')){
            s.erase(i,1);

              }    
             if ((s[i]== ',' || s[i]== '.' || s[i]== '!') && s[i+1] != ' '){     
            s.insert(i+1," ");
              } 
            if (i == 0 ){
               putchar (toupper(s[i]));
              }
             if (s[i]== ' ' && s[i+1] == ' ' ){
                s.erase(i,0);    
              } 

            else if (i !=0)
            putchar (tolower(s[i]));       
               }
            }      
        }
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried putting in another IF statement:

```
if ((s[i]== '?' || s[i]== '.' || s[i]== '!') && s[i+1] == ' '){     
           putchar (toupper(s[i+2]));
              }
```

But I'm guessing I would somehow have to get the corrected version so far into a new string for that statement to work, since the putchar (tolower) just puts it back to lowercase again? Or should I just take a different approach than I have so far.

Comment: pratice walking your code and writing down the result of each statement (ie-what the data looks like after the operation). Your additional "if" statement will only work in some conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete solution, since this is homework.  But some hints.  What you’re trying to write is a finite state machine.  It has two states, which you might implement as an `enum`: the initial state, which is the start of a sentence, and another state for the middle of a sentence.  The solution you have now is limited: consider the testcase `maybe.... NO!`

In the initial state, if you encounter an alphanumeric character, you convert it to titlecase (or uppercase, if you only support ASCII) and switch to the medial state.  You echo any non-alphanumeric character you encounter and remain in the initial state.

In the medial state, you convert any characters to lowercase.  If you encounter a period (and possibly an exclamation point, question mark or newline; ask your professor what the requirements are), switch to the initial state.

If you wanted to handle names and proper nouns correctly, you might introduce a third state for the beginning of a word but not a sentence, and preserve the case of the first letter of every word that does not start a sentence.  That way, you would change `my neighbor James` into `My neighbor James` and not `My neighbor james`.  However, that does not appear to be part of the assignment, so follow the requirements and ask the instructor if you have any questions—if you wanted to implement this, he or she would likely approve.

To support Unicode, you would set your `locale`, `imbue` your `wifstream` input and `wofstream` output with it, and use the functions in `<cwctype>` on a `wchar_t`.  It’s not clear whether you’re supposed to, but a good habit to get into.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! We have not gone over this in our class yet, but I'll look into it, and see if I can figure it out, thanks!